# Pie chart, bar chart and graphs using LWUIT

Tags: java-me, charts, lwuit, pie-chart

Has anybody ever drawn charts and graphs using LWUIT? Is it even possible? If it is, can you share with the world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look on this blog, [Charting Components For LWUIT.](http://www.lwuit.com/2008/12/charting-components-for-lwuit.html)

Comment: The post you linked to points to J4Less, a paid charting tool for J2ME. I went into research mode to find a free option. I found this app created waaay back by one Daniel Cachapa, Weight Watch, using LWUIT that contains charts. Furthermore his code is open source and I intend to learn from it. It will definitely work better with the current versions of LWUIT thank the one he used back then. THANK YOU!